# Can't update Shipping Address

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I wanted to display shipping charges on cart page so i have used the event `sales_quote_collect_totals_before` which is working fine. The problem is , in order to show shipping charges on shopping cart I had to set default shipping address from magento admin. Now , When I place order , default shipping address is used and not what i have manually entered in the shipping address field of checkout. I have tried to save shipping address in quote but it is getting overridden when order is placed.

This is my code -

```
public function handleCollect($observer) {

        if (!Mage::getStoreConfig('shipping/origin/applydefaultstoemptyquote'))
            return $this;


        $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();

        $shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress();


        $billingAddress = $quote->getBillingAddress();

        $saveQuote = false;
        if (!$shippingAddress->getCountryId()) {


            $country = Mage::getStoreConfig('shipping/origin/country_id');

            $state = Mage::getStoreConfig('shipping/origin/region_id');

            $postcode = Mage::getStoreConfig('shipping/origin/postcode');

            $method = Mage::getStoreConfig('shipping/origin/shippingmethod');

            $shippingAddress
                    ->setCountryId($country)
                    ->setRegionId($state)
                    ->setPostcode($postcode)
                    ->setShippingMethod($method)
                    ->setCollectShippingRates(true);
            $shippingAddress->save();

            $saveQuote = true;
        } else {
            $country = Mage::getStoreConfig('shipping/origin/country_id');
            $state = Mage::getStoreConfig('shipping/origin/region_id');
            $postcode = Mage::getStoreConfig('shipping/origin/postcode');
            $method = Mage::getStoreConfig('shipping/origin/shippingmethod');

            $shippingAddress
                    ->setCountryId($country)
                    ->setRegionId($state)
                    ->setPostcode($postcode)
                    ->setShippingMethod($method)
                    ->setCollectShippingRates(true);
            $shippingAddress->save();

            $saveQuote = true;
        }
        if (Mage::getStoreConfig('shipping/origin/applydefaultstobillingaddress') && !$billingAddress->getCountryId()) {

            $country = Mage::getStoreConfig('shipping/origin/country_id');
            $state = Mage::getStoreConfig('shipping/origin/region_id');
            $postcode = Mage::getStoreConfig('shipping/origin/postcode');

            $billingAddress
                    ->setCountryId($country)
                    ->setRegionId($state)
                    ->setPostcode($postcode);

            $saveQuote = true;

            $quote->save();
        }
        if ($saveQuote)
            $quote->save();

        return $this;
    }
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: please check admin side shipping address you are added. Normally its working fine.

Comment: Thank you. It is working fine now.

Comment: please post your solution as answer so it help to other.